# Filter data in spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, filter

Dont know if this is possible but I want to call my data and filter it , so for example notification type will be for example 1 or 2 and then give me everything with a 1 and a 2
My Model

```
public class Notifications {
        @Id
        private String id;
        private String notificationMsg;
        private String notificationType;
        private Date createdDate = new Date();


   //Get all Notification by type
    @RequestMapping(value = "/all/{notificationType}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<Notifications> getAllByNotificationType(@PathVariable("notificationType") String notificationType) {
        List<Notifications> notifications= this.notificationRepository.findByNotificationType(notificationType);
        return user;
    }
```

Or should I add to the model and create a interface like this

```
  List<Notifications> findByNumber1ORNumber2ORNumber3(String Number1,String Number2,String Number3);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `in` clause :

https://javadeveloperzone.com/spring/spring-jpa-query-in-clause-example/

`List<Employee> findByEmployeeNameIn(List<String> names)`;